# Jquery - Should I not repeat selectors (store in a variable)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are some times when I find myself repeating a selector several times. Should I be somehow storing a jquery object to a variable and then just using that one? As a quick example, what about the following?:

```
$('a.contactus').css('padding', '10px');
$('a.contactus').css('margin', '4px');
$('a.contactus').css('display', 'block');
```

Now I know this isn't a great example, since effectively you could just chain each css function. But suppose in between each of those was a conditional statement or something to stop you from chaining.

Can I store a jquery object in a variable? And if so, when should I / can I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
var myvar = $('a.contactus');
myvar.css('padding', '10px').css('margin', '4px').css('display', 'block');
```

but for readability i do this

```
var myvar = $('a.contactus');
myvar.css('padding', '10px')
  .css('margin', '4px')
  .css('display', 'block');
```

basically every time you use $(someselector)  you iterate through the dom. If you can you should store the element reference.

Comment: It should be noted that neither of these is a good solution for this example (see the other answers)...but also *please* make sure your answer is at least correct if it's accepted.

Answer (score 12):

When reusing it more than once (and you can't chain) storing it in a variable isn't a bad idea, the more often it's used or the more expensive the selector, the better idea storing it as a variable becomes.  For example the performance of `$(this)` a few times is trivial, but the performance of `$("[attr=val]")` is *very* poor and should absolutely be cached if reused.  If in doubt, cache it as a variable.

---

Just another tip, in that example you can also pass an object to [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$('a.contactus').css({ padding: '10px', margin: '4px', display: 'block' });
```

Answer (score 4):

> Should I be somehow storing a jquery
>   object to a variable and then just
>   using that one?

You should for the sake of ***performance*** when possible. You can for example re-write your code like this:

```
var $el = $('a.contactus');
$el.css('padding', '10px');
$el.css('margin', '4px');
$el.css('display', 'block');
```

You can make it even shorter like this:

```
$el.css({
  padding: '10px',
  margin:'4px',
  display: 'block'
});
```

Storing common/repetitive selector in a variable is also useful when writing jquery plugins to store the `$(this)` in a variable.

Comment: You should no always store a reference, unless it's used more than once it's *worse* for performance.

Comment: @Nick Craver: Yeah true agreed.