# Why Create jQuery Object Variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see a lot of jQuery examples that do something like

```
var $element = $('#element');
$element.foo...
```

rather than just typing

```
$('#element').foo...
```

and I do realize there is a small bit of typing saved if you are working with
    $element
a lot, but what about those times that
    $element
is only called once or twice? Why do some developers declare it as a jQuery object variable in those instances? Is it also more efficient for the browser to process?

Comment: If you're only re-using it once or twice, then no, there's no real improvement at all.

Comment: You save maybe 6-7 bytes everytime it's minified, and that's something.

Comment: Why do they do it when it's only used once? Who knows. You'd have to ask the developer. Why when only twice? It's a judgement call, and depends on the situation. Is the code in a loop? In a rapidly invoked event handler?

Comment: @cookiemonster - while it is a judgment call, re-querying the DOM for the same object twice is not a good judgment. Caching it when it is only used once serves no benefit, but caching it on multiple uses (even as little as two) is always more efficient because it prevents the DOM from being queried multiple times for the same object.

Comment: It doesn't work because jQuery has no `foo` method !!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @PlantTheIdea that's exactly what I was wondering, if it keeps the browser from querying the object again.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea: I agree with that. Given that the OP seems to have decided already that the savings aren't worthwhile, I didn't want to fight it at that level.

Comment: @adeneo But apparently jQuery UI does: http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.8/#properties-moved-from-ui-foo-to-ui-foo-prototype :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery - Should I not repeat selectors (store in a variable)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918079/jquery-should-i-not-repeat-selectors-store-in-a-variable)

Comment: @adeneo: It's relative. Something is always a lot more than nothing. As a matter of principle, I'd cache it, but as I said above, I didn't want to fight the battle at that level. If someone wants to re-query the DOM, it's up to them.

Comment: Using the selector in the question, which uses getElementById underneath, looking up the element in a simple DOM one, two maybe three times, is probably faster than creating the reference to a new variable, scope, GB etc. and then looking up the element in the jQuery object etc. so there's no guarantee that caching selectors always will be faster, and for a selector like this, even looked up hundreds of times in modern fast browsers, the difference is minescule.

Comment: @adeneo: Not a chance. If we were *only* talking about `getElementById`, it would be closer, but doing it via jQuery is typically something like 30x slower than directly via `getElementById`. You think just creating and GC'ing the variable will be slower? Think again. Heck, think of all the variables that need to be created and GC'd just in the jQuery internal functions.

Comment: A lot of that is the object lookup when you use the jQuery collection for something, and you'd still have that with the variable reference, it still references the object representation of the node, otherwise you wouldn't be able to use it. Of course it's faster to use a variable, but you'd have to use that variable a lot to notice a difference, and most of the time you have access to the `this` keyword, or you have to change the collection somehow, and then you end up only using the variable a few times, and the savings are lost. It makes no sense to cache a collection to use it a few times

Comment: @adeneo - "its only marginally better" is hardly a reason to specifically not do something. if its better, do it. (btw, no one has discussed maintenance or future extensibility of code expansion here ... that definitely comes into play).

Comment: @adeneo: Like I said, I really don't want to fight the battle at this level. I'd cache it. If you don't want to, that's fine too. I avoid memory allocation, others done care as much. People are simply going to have different opinions on this.

Comment: @PlantTheIdea - actually it is, there are a lot of things that would be "better" in many cases in javascript, but micro optimization it usually avoided, and I'm guessing jQuery could get the element by ID about 1 500 000  times each second, and native code probably around 30 000 000 every second, and if looking up the variable took zero time you would still need a helluva a lot of lookups to save *noticeable* time.

Comment: @adeneo -  "micro optimization is usually avoided" ... you and i come from very, very different perspectives then.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Usually this is done to avoid either re-wrapping an element or re-querying the page for the selector.

Such as in a click event

```
$('.className').click(function(){
 var $this = $(this);
 callSomeHelper($this);
 $this.hide();
 if( $this.data("placement") == "somePlacement" ){
  //some logic
 }
});
```

The real saver is when it is referencing a set of elements.

```
var $allSides = $('.side');
```

And now back in the click event, you can reference this without having to re-query

```
$('.top').click(function(){
   var door = $allSides.find(':visible');
});
```

There are obviously more in depth examples, but these two are the main cases that the variable is stored.

Answer (score -3):

It prevents from overwriting variable from another script