# Not repeating selectors in a conditional statement with JavaScript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, conditional-statements

I have a small app with one form and one input field. When a user submits this form, I first want to see if the value only contains letters. If all is good, I want to pass the value on to a function.

Here's what I have:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {

    if ($('input').val().match(/^[a-zA-Z]+$/)) {

        someFunction($('input').val());

    } else {

        // Error message or something else here
    }

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I don't like writing `$('input').val()` twice (once in the conditional statement, and again if it holds true). Using `this` wouldn't work, since it's within a conditional statement and not some sort of function... Is there a way to not repeat code in this scenario?

Perhaps setting `$('input').val()` to a variable would be best?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you just start programming yesterday? You don't know how to assign something to a variable if you don't wat to repeat it?

Comment: Two days ago to be more specific *rolls eyes* If you look at the end of my question, I said, "Perhaps setting $('input').val() to a variable would be best?" I was only asking if that would be BEST. But thanks for the help anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

```
var inputValue = $('input').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit old but I found this helpful : [Not repeating selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918079/jquery-should-i-not-repeat-selectors-store-in-a-variable)

```
var myvar = $('input');
```

As well as the clear discription :

basically every time you use $(someselector) you iterate through the dom. If you can you should store the element reference